# HTML5 Date and time form

Tags: html

I just started HTML and created this form:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title> HTML5 Testing Nitesh </title>
    <meta charset ="utf-8">
  </head>
  <body>
    <form method = "get" action="http://www.msn.com">
      <p>
        <label> Enter Colour Code </label>
        <input type ="color" autofocus /> 
      </p>
      <p>
        <label> Enter The Date </label>
        <input type = "date"/>
      </p>
      <p>
        <label> Enter date with time </label>
        <input type = "datetime" />
      </p>
      <p>
        <label> Enter local date and time </label>
        <input type = "datetime-local" />
      </p>
      <br/><br/>
      <input type = "submit"  value="Submit"/>
      <input type = "reset" value="Reset"/>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Now the problem is I can't enter values properly for date with time and local date with time (tried Google Chrome, Microsoft Edge and IE) although just date column opens up calendar box to input the date.

Answer (score -1):

Try with the below code it may help you.

```js
$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
  format: 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss',
  language: 'pt-BR'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://tarruda.github.com/bootstrap-datetimepicker/assets/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js">
    </script>
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="http://tarruda.github.com/bootstrap-datetimepicker/assets/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css">

<div id="datetimepicker" class="input-append date">
    <input type="text" placeholder="dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss"/>
    <span class="add-on">
      <i data-time-icon="icon-time" data-date-icon="icon-calendar"></i>
     </span>
</div>
```

Comment: This takes the question out of HTML 5  @iqbal